# how to convert CSV file to Json file for below attached data using python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am new to python. I need to convert below csv file to Json file format using python/pandas.
**Input CSV File:**

```
ID  F_Name  L_Name  Address SSN     Phone
123 Sam     Doe     123     12345   111-111-1111
123 Sam     Doe     123     12345   222-222-2222
123 Sam     Doe     abc345  12345   111-111-1111
123 Sam     Doe     abc345  12345   222-222-2222
```

**Expected Output JSON File:**

```
myschema = {
"ID":"123"
"F_Name":"Sam"
"L_Name":"Doe"
"Addess":"[123, abc345]"
"Phone":"[111-111-1111,222-222-2222]"
"SSN":"12345"
}
```

**Code Tried**

```
import json

filename = 'Input_Files/flat_test_file.txt'
dict1 = {}
fields = ['id','fname', 'lname', 'address', 'ssn','phone']
with open(filename) as fh:
    l = 1
    for line in fh:
        description = list(line.strip().split(",", 6))
        print(description)
        i = 0
        dict2 = {}
        while i < len(fields):
            dict2[fields[i]] = description[i]
            i = i + 1
        dict1[sno] = dict2
        l = l + 1
out_file = open("test2.json", "w")
json.dump(dict1, out_file, indent=6)
out_file.close()
```

**Output Getting**

Comment: Having hard time to solve this.

Comment: Can you show what code you've tried so far?

Comment: @Andy I have edit my question and put the cod there

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion :

Read on "to_json" feature, in pandas docs.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(your_file_dir_goes_here)

result = df.to_json(orient="index")
parsed = json.loads(result)

parsed
```

There is the output i got :

```
{'0': {'ID': 123,
  'F_Name': 'Sam',
  'L_Name': 'Doe',
  'Address': 123,
  'SSN': 12345,
  'Phone': '111-111-1111'},
 '1': {'ID': 123,
  'F_Name': 'Sam',
  'L_Name': 'Doe',
  'Address': 123,
  'SSN': 12345,
  'Phone': '222-222-2222'},
 '2': {'ID': 123,
  'F_Name': 'Sam',
  'L_Name': 'Doe',
  'Address': 'abc345',
  'SSN': 12345,
  'Phone': '111-111-1111'},
 '3': {'ID': 123,
  'F_Name': 'Sam',
  'L_Name': 'Doe',
  'Address': 'abc345',
  'SSN': 12345,
  'Phone': '222-222-2222'}}
```

Comment: I need output in multivalue for column as mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0):

myschema = df.groupby('ID', as_index=False).agg(pd.unique).to_dict(orient='records')